# Erlang: is a name without double quotes, still a string or something else?

Tags: string, shell, variables, erlang, quote

I'm new to Erlang, just tried the shell:

```
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
1> Hello=hello.
hello
2> Hello.
hello
3> Point={point,10,45}.
{point,10,45}
4> Point2={"point",10,45}.
{"point",10,45}
```

In `Point`, the first element is `'point'`, there's no variable named point so it's not a reference, there's no double `""`, so it's not a string. But shell doesn't report any error.

So what is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an atom. From the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html):

*Is a literal, a constant with name. An atom is to be enclosed in single quotes (') if it does not begin with a lower-case letter or if it contains other characters than alphanumeric characters, underscore (*), or @_

So `point` it's a valid Erlang term.
Same idea applies to `hello` too.